# Any method or way to bypass an automatically starting workflow?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual-studio

I have a solution in C# where users are able to submit a lengthy form, which then automatically kicks off a workflow that was created in Designer.

However, I am looking to add functionality to the solution which will allow a user to temporary "Save" the form.  This saving function basically consists of temporarily disabling the form validation, and blocking the workflow from starting.

I have a DisableValidators() function which works, however I cannot find a way to bypass the automatic start of the workflow.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not think you can block the workflow from starting, you can create a hidden/dummy column that just says whether or not the form is completed (1 or 0 type of thing). When you save the form it will NOT change this column, but when you submit it, you programmatically set it to the appropriate value.

Then all you have to do is make sure your workflow checks this value before running through your workflow logic and skips to the end. The downside here is the workflow will say completed even if it has not done its logic yet. You could of course use another read-only column to have a custom handled 'completed' column, but its up to you if you want it there at all.

Finally, make sure the workflow runs on item added AND item updated.

Let me know if this is appropriate!

Comment: This sounds great to me, thank you - I will apply this methodology to the solution and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Change the workflow to trigger on change instead of on creation.  That way the item can be saved to the list, then triggered after making their revisions.

Comment: that doesn't handle the cases where the user completed it in one go, and where there are multiple saves

Comment: Then you'll need to incorporate something to what Zork mentions, a hidden field the gets promoted to the list that is the trigger for the work flow that starts on creation or change.